# Click outside of element doesn't work unless the target is much farther in the hierarchy

Tags: jquery, html

I've written a function that detects a click outside a div and its span children. This div is inside a form and several other divs. However, the event doesn't trigger unless the click is outside the form and all parent divs.

Simplified HTML

```
<body>

<!--any other element here activates the code-->

<div>
  <div>
     <div>
        <form>
          <div id="exist-tags"><span class=".tag">Text</span></div>
        </form
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

jQuery excerpt:

```
$(document).on('click',function(e){
    if(e.target!=$("#exist-tags")){
        console.log("works");
    }
});
```

It only logs when I click completely outside of the first div.

Comment: Forms are designed to intercept keyboard and mouse events generated by the user. So the body does not "hear" anything unless you click outside of the form. To fix this, set up a listener on the form instead of the document. You should still be able to perform the same test to see whether the desired target was clicked/not clicked.

Comment: Lifesaver! I didn't know that forms stopped events. Would e.preventDefault stop this behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure. There is a cancelable property on event that can be used to test this. Usually e.preventDefault is used when invoking a context (right-click) menu with custom options, and you want to bypass the default browser right-click (back, forward, reload, etc.).